# Split string into two parts and concatenate with another column

Tags: crystal-reports

My string columns look like this:

> Name : AllenEdward
>
> UniqID : 12345678

How can I get this output in my report?

```
Allen12345678  Edward
```

12345678 should be followed by 2 spaces.

Comment: It seems like you need to split first name and last name first.  If this is the only scenario when you have to do it, it is possible.  But if there is other times you need to do this, it may be tricky as there is no way to distinguish first name from last name. Is it possible you need to do this more than once for other strings?

Comment: The value in the column1 is fixed. its not a name. It's unique no for each record with fixed length 20 bytes.I need to split first 10 bytes and concatenate with a value in another column and concatenate with the remaining 10 bytes.Ex: Column1=ABC00000000123456789. Col2=abcdefxyz O/P should be ABC0000000abcdefxyz  123456789

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to figure out the formulas that split the Name column. We don't know what your data looks like, so that's all you. You could write something that adds a space before any capital letters after the first, but you'll have trouble with the more complex last names like `MacDonald`.

---

Once you figure that out, it's a simple matter of using Formula Fields in Crystal. Something like:

```
[FIRST]{table.UniqID} & "  " & [LAST]
```

...where `[FIRST]` and `[LAST]` are the results from your splitting formula.